# Weight initialisation in ANN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

In case of linear regression, each feature column has one coefficient value irrespective of the number of rows.

What about in neural network?

In case of single layered perceptron, whether it works same as linear regression or else the weights vary for each an every row in the feature column?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I got you there.

In a MLP every neuron's output in a layer is a linear regression of all the neurons in the layer just before it, then an activation is, optionally, applied to the layer after doing the linear regression thing.

Every parameter in an ANN is not related to other parmaeters at least value wise.

The number of rows in data is the number of examples or batches and the number of cloumns is the number of features or inputs.

As for weight initialization, there are many techniques. The most common of them is Xavier initialization.

If you meant what is the shape of the matrix containing the weights of a layer, it should be of the shape (n_features,layer_out_size).